# How can I create a react-native UI library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a React Native UI Library that I can share with some of my other React Native projects.

I've tried installing via npm private repo, regular github repo and also git submodules but each time I try to import a React Native component as simple as a `<View />` I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'useContext' of null
```

[image: react native error screen]

And this is as soon as I use the component in my render method by importing it from the external react native project.

Is there something I'm missing? I've tried using the same react-native version on both but still (this doesn't make sense either as other react-native libraries have different versions).